# Magento 2: Why Add/Edit redirect to Admin Dashboard

Tags: magento2, crud

I'm working on simple CRUD (create, read, update and delete) module without grid or ui component, just simple CRUD.

 So when i'm trying to create add/edit form, i've meet some weird issue, when i click on add/edit button, it redirect to my admin dashboard (At first i think it was acl.xml problem, but it wasn't).
 The controller for edit/add is almost excactly like the list/manage controller.
[image]

I've try to find the problem many hours but no chance.

 Here is [my module](https://github.com/saxsax1995/SimpleMagento2CRUD), please take a look.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get URL without formkey.

Add to your

> Aht\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Department\Manage.php

```
public function getAddUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('department/manage/add');
    }
```

and change in

> view/adminhtml/templates/department/manage.phtml

```
$addlUrl = $adminUrl . '/department/manage/add';
```

to

```
$addlUrl = $block->getAddUrl();
```

Comment: thanks, i will try as soon as i can and feedback to you, thanks for answer my question.

Comment: its worked, thanks.